# Как сделать, чтоб колонки не перекрывали футер?

Tags: css

Без колонок футер нормально внизу прибит, ну как к этой странице я подключаю колонки, то все, футер перестает быть прибитом в самый низ страницы. [скриншот страницы](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20140530/m20Q5X5W.png)

Вот сам css код центральной колонки:

```
.centerColumn {
width: 691px;
float: left;
background: #e34456;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Это футер

```
  .hFooter { /* это распорка в основном блоке - резервируем место для подвала */
  height: 40px; /* высота нашего подвала */
}
.footer { /* подвал */
 background: #36638e; /* цвет фона подвала (для наглядности) */
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 12px;
 height: 40px; /* высота подвала */
 margin-top: -40px; /* делаем отрицательный отступ по высоте равный высоте подвла,            чтобы четко вписаться в размер экрана */
```

}

Comment: если используете float: left- необходимо отменить обтекание

Comment: soledar10, обтекание? А где это у меня обтекание, не понял вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте после .centerColumn

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Либо используйте [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) для родителя .centerColumn

Comment: От души! Спасибо вам большое!